the gap (g-) in bootstrap is not working:(
i followed the sample structure of the grid on bootstrap reference but my code doesn't have horizontal gap (only vertical). it's not about the version because when i paste the sample code in my html file, that code still has the gap but my code doesn't. Please help me:(((
<div class="container">
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="item col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="./images/1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <div class="name">Chair 01</div>
                <div class="price">$200</div>
                <div class="btn btn-dark">Add To Cart</div>
            </div>

            <div class="item col-lg-3  col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="./images/1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <div class="name">Chair 01</div>
                <div class="price">$200</div>
                <div class="btn btn-dark">Add To Cart</div>
            </div>

            <div class="item col-lg-3  col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="./images/1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <div class="name">Chair 01</div>
                <div class="price">$200</div>
                <div class="btn btn-dark">Add To Cart</div>
            </div>

            <div class="item col-lg-3  col-sm-6 col-12">
                <img src="./images/1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <div class="name">Chair 01</div>
                <div class="price">$200</div>
                <div class="btn btn-dark">Add To Cart</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

this is what the result looks like
enter image description here

It's not completely clear from the documentation, but the gap utility is just for use with the CSS grid layout module, not columns and rows as you've tried to use it here. For that, you'll need to use the margin and padding utilities for each row.
